# How to encrypt file name on upload and decrypt on download?

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption

Made an ASP.NET web application which receives a file using file upload control and then encrypts file name on upload.

But when I redirect a user to file_address (so this user can download the file) I don't know how can i decrypt the file name now? because a file (for example a `.docx` file) doesn't have code behind.

So when the user downloads the file He/She receives a file with encrypted name!

All files in the server have a encrypted name and not their original name And What i want to know is how to give files their original name when users download files

Comment: while encryption encrypt only name not extension and vise versa

Answer (score 2):

You can't give the user a direct link to the file - rather a page that first decrypts the file, then writes appropriate response headers and sends the decrypted file as a response.

Like `getFile.aspx?encryptedFileName=abcxyz`. In `Init`, `getfile.aspx` loads the encrypted file, decrypts it, then writes appropriate response headers for the file, changing MIME type to whatever the file requires, and sending the decrypted file instead of a web page.

Here's an example of how to do this with a ZIP file. If you need more help after looking at this, let me know. [How do I generate and send a .zip file to a user in C# ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834527/how-do-i-generate-and-send-a-zip-file-to-a-user-in-c-sharp-asp-net)

Comment: Wait , Does it rename the file on the server in this way or it just downloads the fie with a decrypted name?

Comment: It could do either, but it wouldn't inherently rename the file on the server that way - you'd have to add that as another step. It'd be like File(@"c:\encryptedfiles\abcdxyz").SendToClientAs("TheFileYouSaved.xlsx");